# IIS 7 Url Rewrite Not Working

Tags: iis-7, rewrite, url

### Inbound IIS7 Url Rewrite Rule not working

Below is the URL Rewrite rule I've defined.

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect domain.co.uk to www.domain.co.uk" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^domain\.co\.uk(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.co.uk{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

When I go to domain.co.uk it's not redirecting to www.domain.co.uk. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you seen [IIS7 URL Rewrite - Add “www” prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207059/iis7-url-rewrite-add-www-prefix)?

Answer (score 2):

Had to add a condition to get it to work. Like so...

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect root to www" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain\.co\.uk(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.co.uk/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

[URL Rewrite Tips](http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/)